# Counter Example to the Following If - Then Statement

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $f:X \to Y$ is a one-to-one function and $X$ is countable, then Y is countable.

If $f:X \to Y$ is a one-to-one function and $Y$ is countable, then X is countable.

I am having trouble coming up with specific counterexamples to these statements. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: The latter is true; it doesn't have any counterexamples. The former is indeed false. Think about it this way: $Y$ can be *much* larger than the image of $X$ under $f$.

Comment: Take $f(x)=x$ with $X=\mathbb{N}$ and $Y=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Does your definition of countable include finite?

Answer (score 1):

For the first statement, consider $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$; $f(x)=x$.

For the second statement, no counterexamples exist. The image of $f$ has at most cardinality of $Y$, but $Y$ is countable. Then, since $f$ is injective, the domain of $f$ has the same cardinality as the image of $f$. Therefore, $X$ must also be countable. Hence, the statement is in fact true.

Answer (score 0):

1. $X=\mathbb N$ and $Y=\mathbb R$, $f(x)=x$.
2. $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and $Y=\mathbb N$, $f(x)=x$

Comment: 2 is only a counterexample if we take countable to mean countably infinite. My impression was that countable means finite or countably infinite.

Comment: @ FakeAnalyst56, this depends on the definition that the user has, I assume that countable is the set that has cardinality equal to the set of naturals, since the user requests a counterexample for this fact.